# JSON.NET serialization failure

Tags: serialization, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a LINQ-to-SQL object that serializes to XML without a problem. I can call Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject() and I get the JSON result. When I pass the same result as an object in WebAPI I get an error (see below). I built a trace writer to capture the null inner exception path, I'm not sure how I can figure out which item is causing the error if the path is '' ?

```
20130301122959: Started serializing AnvilDB.Partner. Path ''.
20130301122959: Error serializing AnvilDB.Partner. An item with the same key has already been added. Path ''.
Error: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
   at System.Web.Http.Metadata.Providers.AssociatedMetadataProvider`1.CreateTypeInformation(Type type)
   at System.Web.Http.Metadata.Providers.AssociatedMetadataProvider`1.GetTypeInformation(Type type)
   at System.Web.Http.Metadata.Providers.AssociatedMetadataProvider`1.GetMetadataForProperty(Func`1 modelAccessor, Type containerType, String propertyName)
   at System.Web.Http.Validation.ModelValidationRequiredMemberSelector.IsRequiredMember(MemberInfo member)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonContractResolver.ConfigureProperty(MemberInfo member, JsonProperty property)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonContractResolver.CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract(Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract(Type type)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
20130301123002: Started serializing System.Web.Http.HttpError. Path ''.
20130301123002: Started serializing System.Web.Http.HttpError. Path 'InnerException'.
20130301123002: Finished serializing System.Web.Http.HttpError. Path 'InnerException'.
20130301123002: Finished serializing System.Web.Http.HttpError. Path ''.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Digging around I found that I could set up an error handler for the serializer, and then examine the ErrorContext.Member value. This pointed to a property of XElement type. Further searching discovered this is a known/reported bug, but has not yet been fixed; see https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/53

Summary: if you have an XElement property with a null value, JSON.NET fails.

Here is what I added to diagnose the root cause:

```
    base.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Error = (sender, args) =>
    {
        string e = string.Format("{0}: {1}", args.ErrorContext.Member, args.ErrorContext.Path, args.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
        myTracer.Trace(System.Diagnostics.TraceLevel.Error, e, args.ErrorContext.Error);
    };
```

The myTracer was a simple file trace writer.

---

**Update**

I have now found a solution to this bug.

The class that WebAPI uses to serialize a JSON object is not directly from JSON.NET, but is set to an instance of JsonContractResolver, which is located in System.Net.Http.Formatting. Fortunately this is open source, so you can see the current version here:

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/4764b0111b91#src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/Formatting/JsonContractResolver.cs

I copied this exact code to my own class, and replaced the Contract Resolver in JSON.NET with my own class, using this code (unchanged) and the bug was fixed. From this I conclude that the current released WebAPI version (System.Net.Http.Formatting version 4.0.20710.0) has the bug in it, and the next release presumably will fix this issue.

If like me you need to fix it now, here are the steps:

1. Create your own contract resolver class using the JsonContractResolver.cs code
2. Change your startup configuration to override the ContractResolver setting:

Sample:

```
var settings = System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings; 
// create formatter 
var formatter = new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter(); 
settings.ContractResolver = new MyJsonContractResolver(formatter);
```

This should help.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in Web API. I'd recommend filing a bug about it here:

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

In the meantime, I think you can workaround it by setting up your configuration like this:

```cs
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
```

Comment: Thanks .. see my own result - there is a bug, but it's in JSON.NET not in WebAPI.